# X11 VNC server in 17.10

Tags: vncviewer

I cannot get VNCserver to run at all in 17.10 AA.  It ran well in 17.04. When I launch it, It indicates that another version is already running.  I believe the firewall is open.  I have reinstalled 17.10.

Comment: Please provide more information. What exactly you are doing in attempt to run the VNC server? What is the exact error message? *It indicates that another version is already running* or another application uses the same port?

Comment: Not at all sure what else to say.  In earlier installs, it has worked easily.  It simply does not start under 17.10.  I can check to make sure that 4080 is open. ufw status shows inactive ?

Comment: Hi,I have the same problem. On 17:04 the VNC server was setted default. I don't know what configuration was. I just do firsts 2 steps from this tutorial (http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/07/remote-access-ubuntu-16-04/)  and then remote via Remina (config for VNC connected by IP address with password). Don't know what exactly i should to do to back to VNC connections.